# how to render framebuffer directly in opengl es2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, render, framebuffer

I want to create a program that use all fbo made by myself to render. i know the common precedure of rendering like that:
    1. egl init.
    2. program use.
    3. input texture data
    4. swapbuffer.
, but when i changed it into the fbo rendering, something happened that i don't know the reason. here is my code that i added:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1,frame_buf);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frame_buf);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &color_buf);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, s->color_buf);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, screen_width, screen_height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, s->color_buf);
```

i think when i add this, the gl will operate in the binding fbo that i made. but no image show in the window..

Answer (score 0):

Of course no image showed up. Generally speaking, you have to render to the default framebuffer for it to become visible. That's where the visible image is: the default framebuffer.

You can do intermediate rendering to an FBO. But you have to blit or render it to the default framebuffer before your swap buffer call will be of use.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but as i know in ios api, the implement of opengl render all use fbo, which bind to a render layer to show the image. so i wonder whether there is a similar method using egl api to do the same.. could you tell me how to blit the fbo directly to default fbo?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render directly to On-Screen , use this code instead of the code that you used

```
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, screen_width, screen_height);
```

Change

```
[eaglContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)eaglLayer];
```

glRenderbufferStorage() draw to Off-Screen

If you work in Android  follow this rule

```
#ifdef IOS
```

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, s_FrameBuffer);

```
#elif ANDROID
```

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

```
#endif
```

Comment: T T i know that comes from ios api, but the environment i work is android...your advise not work

Comment: I did not mention that . Ok , It's little different to setting FBO between IOS&ANDROID.

Comment: I updated my answer and If you want to render directly don't use glRenderbufferStorage()